# Want to run PRAW bot that only prints else statement once

Tags: python, praw

I am writing a praw bot that goes through a specific subreddit, and grab the titles of each post within a specific limit, 20 posts. It then tries to identify if a specific string("word_to_find") exists in the title of each post.

I want the bot to print out the string, "Can't find Kawhi articles in the subreddit!" if it doesn't find the specified "word_to_find" in any of the post titles.

However, I only want the bot to print the above string one time, and  only if "word_to_find" doesn't exist any of the titles found.

However when the else statement runs within my for loop, it prints out a post with the "word_to_find" string found, and the leftover amount of posts with the above string, all within the limit of 20.

I hope this all makes sense. Below is my current code.

```
    def run_bot():
        sub = r.subreddit('nba')
        print("---Grabbing subreddit---\n")
        subs = sub.top('week', limit=20)
        print("---Grabbing posts in sub---\n")
        print("Looking for Kawhi Articles..\n")
        for posts in subs:
            article_url = posts.url
            post_title = posts.title
            word_to_find = "Kawhi"

            if word_to_find in post_title:
                print(post_title)



            else: 
                print("Can't find Kawhi articles in the 
                         subreddit!")

   run_bot()
```

Comment: Your current `else` needs to run once when none of the `posts` in `subs` have the `word_to_find`, right? You can maintain a boolean variable and only if it is true after the `for` loop ends, print the message.

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes you want to loop through all posts regardless of whether you find a post which has the `word_to_find` in its `post_title`.

```
def run_bot():
    sub = r.subreddit('nba')
    print("---Grabbing subreddit---\n")
    subs = sub.top('week', limit=20)
    print("---Grabbing posts in sub---\n")
    print("Looking for Kawhi Articles..\n")

    not_in_any_post = True
    for posts in subs:
        article_url = posts.url
        post_title = posts.title
        word_to_find = "Kawhi"

        if word_to_find in post_title:
            print(post_title)
            not_in_any_post = False
        else:
            not_in_any_post = not_in_any_post and True

    if not_in_any_post:
        print("Can't find Kawhi articles in the subreddit!")

run_bot()
```

The `not_in_any_post` flag will be `True` only if NONE of the posts have `word_to_find`.

If you want to print the message once as soon as a title is found that doesn't have `word_to_find`, you can use your existing code while adding a `break` statement in the `else` block. However, this means it will not loop over the remaining posts.